# .htaccess url rewrite having issues

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not able to customize a url using .htaccess. I applied all changes in .htaccess but this one stuck with me for long time.

I have a URL :

```
product.php?act=pro&cat=1&category=Nokia
```

I want to change it to:

```
product/1/Nokia.html
```

I used following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^product/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)\.html$ product.php?act=$1&cat=$2&category=$3 [QSA]
```

But not getting this one correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're capturing only 2 groups and using $1, $2, $3.

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /product.php?act=pro&cat=$1&category=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/product/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ ^/product.php?act=pro&cat=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern that matches cat should have 0-9 in it